# TNS-12542: TNS:address already in use TNS-12560:TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, listener

Facing error below when lsnrctl START  start listener.

> Error listening on: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
>   TNS-12542: TNS:address already in use  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter
>   error   TNS-00512: Address already in use    Linux Error: 98: Address
>   already in use

listener.ora content as below. NSMS = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = NSMS)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.99.33.22)(Port = 1522)) ) ) ) SID_LIST_NSMS = (SID_LIST = (SID_DESC = (GLOBAL_DBNAME = NSMS) (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0) (SID_NAME = NSMS) ) ) ADMIN_RESTRICTION_NSMS = ON

sqlnet.ora content NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES) AUTOMATIC_IPC = ON TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = OFF TRACE_FILE_CLIENT = /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/network/trace/client.trc SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 10 TCP.VALIDNODE_CHECKING = YES TCP.INVITED_NODES = (LA) #TCP.EXCLUDED_NODES = (1.22.33.44) # DIAG_SIGHANDLER_ENABLED=NO

tnsname.ora content NSMS = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.99.33.22)(Port = 1522)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = NSMS)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = NSMS) ) )

Comment: Check if the Oracle SID is set. If not please export/ set the SID.

Comment: The extra info you've posted in the comments....please add it to the question and format it, so it's clear for people reading. Use the Edit feature to amend your question. The comments section is not for including code or error messages. Thanks.

Comment: echo $ORACLE_SID
NSMS   ORACLE_SID set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking host name used in listner.ora if file set properly in OS level. Then try working with the default port 1521

Comment: echo $ORACLE_SID NSMS ORACLE_SID set correctly . but still not working